# Efficient way to realize permalinks in php

Tags: php, database, url, url-rewriting, title

What is the most efficient way to realize php-driven permalinks?

Basically I want to reduce the database accesses to a minimum.

What is the best way to redirect to an id stored in the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a db ID based url like SO does:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265061/efficient-way-to-realize-permalinks-in-php
```

or

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265061
```

both go to the same place.

This is usually done through some sort of mod_rewrite redirect to your php file from a .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^/questions/([0-9]+)/?.*$ /questions.php?id=$1
```

The rewrite rule throws away everything after the ID - so you could even go to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265061/not-the-questions-title-anymore
```

And you still reach your destination.  You'll want to add the "title slugs" to the actual URL being 'linked' when you generate the links in php - it will improve your Search Engine Friendliness...

Comment: You took the words of my keyboard ;) ! I may add that the first version is much more SEO-friendly !

Comment: @gnarf: Yes that looks good. I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: @wookai - added a mention about Search Engine Friendliness at your request ;)

Comment: Except the "not-the-questions-title-anymore" leads to duplicate URLs. You should use either ID or "slug", not both. Unless you can guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat You can always use 301 redirection if you detect that the slug isn't correct if you are worried about those duplicate URL's

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple URL-to-ID map to retrieve the ID based on the URL:

```
+----------+----+
| URL path | ID |
+----------+----+
| /foo     | 1  |
| /bar     | 2  |
| /bar/baz | 3  |
| …        | …  |
+----------+----+
```

Comment: I think in my question is this approach included and not a really good answer that helps me. Nevertheless thanks.

Comment: @ChrisBenyamin: So what exactly do you want to know?